# Google UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.formStatus is UMPFormStatusUnAvailable

Tags: ios14, google-mobile-ads

I have implemented google's UMP SDK to add support of EUConsent and Apple's ATT dialog for iOS 14

But I am getting **`UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.formStatus`** = **`UMPFormStatusUnAvailable`** everytime

So it is very annoying

And we are near to release of iOS 14
And I have to be ready for iOS 14 with UMP SDK

Please help if anyone facing this type of issue

It would be very helpful for me

Comment: On 3 September Apple announced an extension period for implementing its new privacy guidelines for iOS 14 and released both more precise details about those privacy guidelines and a new beta version of iOS 14 as well.

https://www.adjust.com/blog/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-delay-to-ios-14-ad-tracking-changes/

Answer (score 0):

3 steps solved the issue for me:

1. deinstall the app
2. trun on: Settings->Privacy->Traking-> Allow Apps to Request to Track
3. reinstall the app

Comment: This wasn't enabled on my device either, but it still didn't solve the problem. One step closer though.